# How to prove the evenly partition is the best case for quick sort algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, computer-science, quicksort

Why we say the bestcase for quicksort is that "each time we perform a partition we divide the list into two nearly equal pieces"? And how to prove this is exactly the so called "best case"?

Comment: If you prove that in this case the complexity is O(n.log(n)) then you proved it is a best case as sorting with comparisons has cost at least O(n.log(n)). To prove it is the sole best case is much harder, has you have to prove that any other partition schema leads to greater complexity.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - any partition scheme that results in some fixed ratio, such as always splitting a partition into 1/4 and 3/4 size, is also O(n log(n)). Showing that this is worse than splitting into 1/2 and 1/2 is a bit harder as you mentioned.

Comment: @rcgldr Yes this only modifies the base of the log, but at the extremum (splitting 1|n-1) or for any constant k in (k|n-k) you fall into O(n^2). That was what I would have meant.

Answer (score 1):

Take array of length `2^N` (for simplicity).

Compare number of operations for the case of perfect partitions at every stage (`N` into `N/2+N/2`) and for the case of division of segment length `N` into `1` and `N-1`

Answer (score 1):

I created a program rather than trying to do an analysis. I compared the case of 1/2, 1/2 (50% 50%) split versus 1/4, 3/4 (25% 75%) split, which appears to approach taking 22% more operations as n becomes large. The code is set for the 1/4,3/4 split:  for 1/2,1/2 split, change the line from left = (n+3)/4 to left = (n+1)/2. The point of rounding left up is to make sure left >= 1, to avoid infinite recursion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
static uint64_t sum;

void qsa(uint64_t n)
{
uint64_t left, right;
    if(n < 2)
        return;
    sum += n;
    left = (n+3)/4;         /* or left = (n+1)/2  */
    right = n - left;
    qsa(left);
    qsa(right);
}

int main()
{
    qsa(1024*1024);
    printf("%llu\n", sum);
    return(0);
}
```

results

```
n = 1024*1024
20971520     1/2 1/2   n log2(n)
25331387     1/4 3/4   ~1.208 n log2(n)

n = 16*1024*1024

402653184    1/2 1/2   n log2(n)
488049677    1/4 3/4   ~1.212 n log2(n)

n = 1024*1024*1024

32212254720  1/2 1/2   n log2(n)
39180282211  1/4 3/4   ~1.216 n log2(n)

n = 16*1024*1024*1024

584115552256 1/2 1/2   n log2(n)
711608157825 1/4 3/4   ~1.218 n log2(n)
```