# Binary vs Linear searches for unsorted N elements

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

I try to understand a formula when we should use quicksort. For instance, we have an array with *N = 1_000_000* elements. If we will search *only once*, we should use a simple *linear search*, but if we'll do it 10 times we should use sort array *O(n log n)*. How can I detect threshold when and for which size of input array should I use sorting and after that use binary search?

Comment: 1,000,000 elements? Why did you write it that way?

Comment: quicksort time complexity varies depending on the data. Using merge sort instead would avoid this issue, as the number of moves is always the same and worst case number of compares is n ⌈ log2(n) ⌉, while best case number of compares is 1/2 the worst case.

Comment: @RyanSchaefer it doesn't matter. I just choose some big input value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to solve inequality that rougly might be described as

```
t * n > C * n * log(n) + t * log(n)
```

where `t` is number of checks and `C` is some constant for sort implementation (should be determined experimentally). When you evaluate this constant, you can solve inequality numerically (with uncertainty, of course)

Comment: Thanks for the response! How can I define **t** if an element for searching can be changed every time?

Comment: @Danzis I think he means that `t` is the number of searches that will be performed

Comment: Yes, SirGuy is right, Threshold value for array length n depends on the number of searches t (and vice versa, if you want to determine for given array length how many searches is worth to make linearly)

Comment: @MBo, sorry, but I don't understand what for we need ***C***? Could you explain more detail, please?

Comment: Algorithm implementations have asymptotic complexity and some constant factor that does not cahnge complexity but influences on run time. Linear search requires one index increment, one comparison per step and some smemory writes, so number of operations can reach `3*N` (corresponds to linear complexity `O(N)`). For quicksort number of operations is about  `C*N*log(N)` where `C` depends on quicksort implementation. For example, Lomuto partitions makes more swaps and is slower than Hoare partition. Specific implementation might change threshold by some factor.

Comment: @MBo Thanks a lot for detail explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Like you already pointed out, it depends on the number of searches you want to do. A good threshold can come out of the following statement:

`n*log[b](n) + x*log[2](n) <= x*n/2` x is the number of searches; n the input size; b the base of the logarithm for the sort, depending on the partitioning you use.

When this statement evaluates to true, you should switch methods from linear search to sort and search.

Generally speaking, a linear search through an unordered array will take n/2 steps on average, though this average will only play a big role once x approaches n. If you want to stick with big Omicron or big Theta notation then you can omit the `/2` in the above.

Comment: The calculation requires knowing the base for the logarithm function.

Comment: Since we would be dealing with average number of comparisons, I think the RHS should be `x*n/2` since a linear search searches half data on average

Comment: @rcgldr You are right, though this depends on his partitioning for the sort if I am correct. I could take a guess but I think it would be a bit wild to just throw around numbers when I don't know them for sure. I'll update it for binary search though.

Comment: @rcgldr Probably use 2 as the logarithm base unless you have a reason to use something else (like knowing more information about your data)

Comment: @SirGuy, had it like that at first and deleted it again since I believe it did not matter too much, will update again with a disclaimer on the size, thanks.

Comment: @MrDeal - I did a comparison of even split versus 1/4, 3/4 split in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54759382/how-to-prove-the-evenly-partition-is-the-best-case-for-quick-sort-algorithm/54786424#54786424) . The 1/4,3/4 split took about 22% more operations. I didn't take cache issues into account. This doesn't address potential worst case behavior, which is why I would recommend merge sort, since it is more consistent time wise, and generally faster than quick sort with worst case behavior avoided.

Comment: @rcgldr I would recommend MS, too but OP asked for QS, as already pointed out to you in another answer's comments. You are probably aware of the paper by McIlroy and Bentley ["Engineering a Sort Function"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.8162&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which handles the issue of partitioning. This partitioning method will result in `O(n*log[2]n)` (see p. 7 or 1255-56). The function described in the paper is the `qsort` in C and it is as good as a merge on average.

Comment: @MrDeal - Using a median of 9 with quick sort is enough to make it a bit slower than merge sort. The only advantage is it uses O(log(n)) stack space instead of O(n) space for a second array. On a processor with 16 registers, such as X86 in 64 bit mode, 8 of them used to reference the current and end locations of runs (assuming compiler optimization will use them this way), a 4 way bottom up merge sort is about the same or slightly faster than a quicksort using middle element as pivot (no median of 3 or 9).

Comment: @rcgldr what do you mean with "a median of 9"? Do you mean the position of the pivot? Also quick side note, I agree with you, BUT I stuck to the question.

Comment: @MrDeal - pages 1255-1256 in the pdf file you linked to is describing median of 9 (using 3 median of 3 calls). Visual Studio uses intro sort, using insertion sort for sub_array size <= 32 elements, and median of 9 for partition for it's template version of std::sort.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `n` elements and `m` searches, with crude approximations

- the cost of the sort will be `C0.n.log n`,
- the cost of the `m` binary searches `C1.m.log n`,
- the cost of the `m` linear searches `C2.m.n`,

with `C2 ~ C1 < C0`.

Now you compare

```
C0.n.log n + C1.m.log n vs. C2.m.n
```

or

```
C0.n.log n / (C2.n - C1.log n)  vs. m
```

For reasonably large `n`, the breakeven point is about `C0.log n / C2`.

For instance, taking `C0 / C2 = 5`, `n = 1000000` gives `m = 100`.

Answer (score 0):

You should plot the complexities of both operations.

> Linear search: O(n)
>
> Sort and binary search: O(nlogn + logn)

In the plot, you will see for which values of `n` it makes sense to choose the one approach over the other.

Comment: Plotting would requires knowing the base of the logarithm. log[2](n) would be a best case scenario, log[4/3](n) assumes an average split of 1/4, 3/4, and would take about 22% more operations. Worst case behavior without a hybrid sort like intro sort (or use merge sort instead) would be O(n^2).

Comment: The average case should be used @rcgldr.

Comment: Average case for quicksort is complicated, and depends on assumptions. A common assumption is worst case happens 1/2 of the time and the rest of the time it's 1/4 3/4 split or better, with about 40% more operations than best case. Merge sort doesn't have this issue (number of moves is always the same, compare count best case is 1/2 of compare count worst case. However the OP specifically mentioned quicksort.

Comment: @rcgldr worst case happens 1/2 the time? That doesn't sound random at all, in which case a better algorithm could handle that kind of data better.

Comment: @SirGuy - this is what I read when doing a web search for "quicksort average case". Again, the web sites are using assumptions that I don't see any evidence of research to validate those assumptions. I"m not sure this is important. 1 million elements can be sorted in under a second on most PCs using merge sort, so I don't see a reason for choosing to use quick sort, since by the time you eliminate worst case behavior, it is slower than merge sort.

Answer (score 0):

This actually turned into an interesting question for me as I looked into the expected runtime of a quicksort-like algorithm when the expected split at each level is not 50/50.
the first question I wanted to answer was for random data, what is the average split at each level. It surely must be greater than 50% (for the larger subdivision). Well, given an array of size N of random values, the smallest value has a subdivision of (1, N-1), the second smallest value has a subdivision of (2, N-2) and etc. I put this in a quick script:

```
split = 0
for x in range(10000):
  split += float(max(x, 10000 - x)) / 10000
split /= 10000
print split
```

And got exactly 0.75 as an answer. I'm sure I could show that this is always the exact answer, but I wanted to move on to the harder part.

Now, let's assume that even 25/75 split follows an nlogn progression for some unknown logarithm base. That means that `num_comparisons(n) = n * log_b(n)` and the question is to find `b` via statistical means (since I don't expect that model to be exact at every step). We can do this with a clever application of least-squares fitting after we use a logarithm identity to get:

```
C(n) = n * log(n) / log(b)
```

where now the logarithm can have any base, as long as `log(n)` and `log(b)` use the same base. This is a linear equation just waiting for some data! So I wrote another script to generate an array of `xs` and filled it with `C(n)` and `ys` and filled it with `n*log(n)` and used `numpy` to tell me the slope of that least squares fit, which I expect to equal `1 / log(b)`. I ran the script and got `b` inside of `[2.16, 2.3]` depending on how high I set `n` to (I varied n from 100 to 100'000'000). The fact that `b` seems to vary depending on `n` shows that my model isn't exact, but I think that's okay for this example.

To actually answer your question now, with these assumptions, we can solve for the cutoff point of when: `N * n/2 = n*log_2.3(n) + N * log_2.3(n)`. I'm just assuming that the binary search will have the same logarithm base as the sorting method for a 25/75 split. Isolating `N` you get:

```
N = n*log_2.3(n) / (n/2 - log_2.3(n))
```

If your number of searches `N` exceeds the quantity on the RHS (where `n` is the size of the array in question) then it will be more efficient to sort once and use binary searches on that.