# When Linear Search is better than Binary Search for unsorted array? And which sorting algorithm goes with Binary Search to sort the array first?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search

I understand that an unsorted array needs to be sorted first before applying Binary Search. So consider time complexity comparison of a Sorting algorithm + Binary search vs Linear Search.

Comment: Binary search cannot be applied to unsorted array. So what is real question?

Comment: I already mentioned which sorting algorithm is better to sort the elements first. I should have mentioned that in the question itself.

Comment: Binary search cannot be applied to unsorted arrays , it just wont work.

Comment: I already mentioned which sorting algorithm is better to sort the elements first. As most of the people missed the essence, I edited the question. I hope it is clearly communicating the question.

Comment: Perhaps your collegue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891975/binary-vs-linear-searches-for-unsorted-n-elements)

Answer (score -2):

Binary search is better when total numbers of elements are < 10e6

Linear Search has O(n) complexity where as Binary search has O(logn).
10e6 = 7.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the reason?

Comment: It is too brave sentence ;)

Comment: This has no discernable relationship with reality.